# How can i image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, assetbundle, flutter-assetimage

Flutter assest bundle not exists, i don't know how to fix this problem. please anybody help me to solve this prroblem.Anybody say that error in above screenshot.I cannot find that error please help me.how can i solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYgVp.png)

Comment: Have you run the pub get command? Have you added the assets configuration in your pubspec.yaml file? Is your image in the right folder? You can also try calling the image by "images/bus1.jpg" instead... sometimes the part "assets" is not necessary...

Answer (score 2):

Your image is not in the same location as you are calling it in your project.

You are calling `assets/images/bus1.jpg` but you've put your image into your project's main folder. This is not correct.

Create an `assets` folder within your project and in that folder, you can create one `images` folder, and place your image in there.

```
ProjectFolder:
    -build
    -ios
    -lib
    ...
    -assets
        -images 
            -bus1.jpg
```

Then, you will also need to add your asset to your configuration file called `pubspec.yaml`, under your main project folder.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/bus1.jpg
```

Use the following link, to learn how to use [Assets and Images](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

if you have not added this in `pubspec.yaml`
add this & `pub get` to get the packages done.

```
flutter:  
  assets:
   - assets/
   - assets/images/
```

if this doesn't solves it can you please show the structure of the project (i mean the folders flow) so that we can figure the path of the asset image accordingly.